# How to return a single object instead of a collection in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to **return a single object** instead of a collection in *Laravel*. Actually this code works:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $facture = Facture::where('id', '=', $id)->with('items')->with('client')->get();
    return Response::json($facture[0]);
}
```

but I Would like to know if it's the right way to do it?

Comment: Use the `first()` method instead of `get()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While `first()` works for any kind of query, when you are fetching a model by id `find()` is the preferred method. Also you can combine the two `with` calls:

```
$facture = Facture::with('items', 'client')->find($id);
```

Comment: Great, I like this compact way to do it! Is find($id) faster than first() ?

Comment: `find()` actually does nothing else than adding a where condition for the primary key (`where('id', '=', $id)`) and then calling `first()`. But the syntax is nicer and you don't have to specify the name of the primary key everywhere :)

Comment: The `first` method also works fine and returns a single object instead of array!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the right code to get only a single object instead of a collection:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $facture = Facture::where('id', '=', $id)->with('items')->with('client')->first();
    return Response::json($facture);
}
```

Comment: I just tried without the [0] and it works! Please update your answer ;)

Comment: @LucienDubois Yes, I noticed that before your comment and have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out though.